# How to list a property of an entity in C# that is of list type in the front end?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity, subsonic

I have the class below Person and it has a list of its dependents. My question is how to render this on the screen, let's say I have a table of people and when clicking on one another table of dependents is displayed, if there are many records it could cost the database a lot of time. How to do this to get better performance? In the example below, each time I get the Dependents of Person property, I search through a function for the Person id.

```
public class  Dependent
   {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set;}
   }

public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set;}
        private List<Dependent> _dependents;
        public List<Dependent> Dependentes
{ 
  get {return _dependents = getDependentsForDatabase(this.Id);}

set { _dependents = value };

}

var dependents = new Person().Dependents;
Console.WriteLine(dependents);
```

I'm using Subsonic, but I'd like ideas regardless of the bank connection tool.

Answer (score 0):

1.why not inherit from List?

```
List<T> does implement several interfaces.
```

2.How to Sort a List by a property in the object

```
SortedList<T>.
```

3.What is the best way to give a C# auto-property an initial value?

```
Constructor, Field
```

4.How do I calculate someone's age based on a DateTime type birthday?

```
class Program
{
    public int CalculateAge(DateTime birthDate)
    {
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Today;
        int age = currentDate.Year - birthDate.Year;
        if (birthDate.Date > currentDate.AddYears(-age))
            age--;

        return age;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime birthDate = new DateTime(1998, 8, 15); // My birth date
        int age = new Program().CalculateAge(birthDate);
        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + age);
    }
}
```

5.How can I retrieve Id of inserted entity using Entity framework?

Using `DbContext.Add()` method with `Asynchronous` SaveChanges: If you're working with `asynchronous` operations, you can use `await` `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` and then access the generated Id.

```
using (var dbContext = new YourDbContext())
{
   // Create a new entity
   var newEntity = new YourEntity 
   { 
    // Populate properties
    };

   // If using asynchronous SaveChanges
   dbContext.YourEntities.Add(newEntity);
   await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
   int newEntityId = newEntity.Id;
}
```

6.What is the difference between a field and a property?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int myField;

    // Property declaration
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return myField; } // Getter
        set { myField = value; } // Setter
    }
}
```

7.How do I view the `SQL` generated by the `Entity Framework`?

several options depending on the version of `Entity Framework` you're using and your development environment.

8.How to set the Content-Type header for an `HttpClient` request?

```
// Set the Content-Type header
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.
Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

9.How do I call a generic method using a Type variable?

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod();
MethodInfo genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeArgument);
```